# Targetting a class in Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

New to Selenium for Python 2.7

How does one target an  with class create and get it to click?

```
<a href="#" class="create"></a>
```

What I'm trying to do:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
import unittest, time, re
self.driver.find_element_by_link_text("create").click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use XPath or CSS Selectors to find the target elements:

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector('a[class="create"]')
element.click()
```

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the built in finder for classes.

```
element = self.driver.find_element_by_class_name("create")
element.click()
```